# font-weight: bold not working in IE 7 and 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm applying the following CSS:

```
dl dd {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;      
}
```

but my text is not bold in IE?

HTML:

```
<dl><dt>Prepared For</dt><dd><pre>( client name )</pre></dd></dl>
```

I think it might have something to do with the `<pre>` tags, because when they aren't there, it's bolded.

The font family is Arial.

Comment: Would you mind showing us the HTML this CSS is being applied to?

Comment: Is the style really being applied? Try adding `!important`. Please provide a demo if you could. And also, what font family is it? Some obscure one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of a definition list should be something like:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Some title</dt>
    <dd>Your definition</dd>
</dl>
```

Do you have anything other than text in the `<dd>` that might have styles being applied to them that override your `dl dd` CSS, like a `<span>` or `<strong>` or `<em>`?

**EDIT:**

Saw your update. It definitely DOES have to do with your `<pre>` tags. Your CSS rules don't override the `<pre>` because that sort of defeats the purpose of "pre-formatted text."

Try expanding your CSS to include `<pre>` in the chain of selectors, and if that fails, you may need to use `!important` (although this is generally frowned upon):

```css
dl dd pre {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold !important; /* remove !important if not needed */
}
```

See if that works and report back.